# Unable to access test resources from junit tests

Tags: java

Edit: Turns out I hadn't rebuilt the program in a while.  If all the other answers for this kind of problem are not working for you, try rebuilding!  Thanks Timo!

I've looked at a ton of answers and tried a bunch of stuff.  I know I must be doing something extremely minor wrong.  If anyone has a quick tip please let me know, this is slowly killing me.

My directory setup is:
[image]

I'm trying to read in testDom.xml with

```
File testFile = new File(getClass().getResource("testDom.xml").getFile());
```

I've tried loading from the class:

```
File testFile = new File(GemsDomGetChildrenTest.class.getResource("testDom.xml").getFile());
```

I've tried both with the path as

```
/lambda-compiler/src/test/resources/testDom.xml
/src/test/resources/testDom.xml
/test/resources/testDom.xml
/resources/testDom.xml
/testDom.xml
testDom.xml
```

And I've tried all those paths without leading '/' as well.

The resources folder also seems to be added as a test resource in IntelliJ too:

[image]

I get that this is probably a duplicative question and has been asked a million times, but I'm really struggling to see what I'm doing differently than all the other questions I've viewed so far.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code you mentioned? Is it in src/test/java? Just making sure it's not in src/main/java or something.

Comment: it's in /src/test/java/com.gems.compiler.services/GemsDomGetChildrenTest.java... Does the test resource need to be in a similarly-named package under /src/test/resources as well?

Comment: No, it can be placed in the root. You are allowed to create directories there however, should you ever need/want to.

Comment: And what is your goal? Because you've got a File handle here, you need to do some addtional stuff to read in the content.

Comment: @Timo - I'd like to be able to read in testDom.xml from my unit test so I can test some service methods which do some custom parsing.  I'll eventually do more stuff with it, but I'm getting a NPE when I try to create the file handle because getResource() is returning null.

Comment: @Timo - more specifically I'll be passing the file handle to a javax.xml DocumentBuilder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184779/discussion-between-timo-and-zyd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so Timo was able to figure it out.  I hadn't rebuilt the project for a while (:facepalm:).  Coming from the python world here, where things are a little different. Thanks for working through this with me everyone, it really means a lot!

Comment: and check the box, so the question is closed :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `getResource("/testDom.xml")`

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting a null pointer with this.  I've tried every path between starting with the package name and just using "testDom.xml", with and without the forward slash.  Is there more info I could provide to help debug the situation?

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
URL resource = GemsDomGetChildrenTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("testDom.xml");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
```

Comment: I know right? Still getting a null pointer though.  Is there more information I could provide that would help?

Comment: Well, just i've just created the same stucture as on the screenshot and run the code above - no NPE. My test class is also under a package (not default). No idea what could be wrong there(

Comment: @zyd, Are you sure you've tried with my option (class.getClassloader()...)?

Comment: hey thanks for your help, turned out I hadn't rebuilt the program for a while.  I knew it was a super simple oversight somewhere.  Your answer does work correctly.